# Android, listView, my text does not fit as wished

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am trying to make a ListView with 2 TextView and 2 ImageViews.
[image]

I want that "Location" TextView is under the "name" TextView and not at the right!

Here's the code so far of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_widget_text"/>

        <ImageView

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/list_vertical_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_edit"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_widget_bg"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="50dip"/>

        <ImageView

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/list_vertical_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_widget_bg"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="50dip" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 2 `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` like this

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">     

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_widget_text"/> 
<LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Apoorv's method is nice too, I would prefer using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` for that, it would give you more flexibility:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_widget_text"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_widget_edit"
            android:src="@drawable/list_vertical_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_edit"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_widget_bg"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="50dip"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_widget_delete"
            android:src="@drawable/list_vertical_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_widget_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_widget_bg"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="50dip" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```